# Read cookies which was sent from nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

I have an application where i set cookie from backend like:

```js
res.cookie('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token, {httOnly: true});
```

And after login, i try to read the cookie on front end:

```js
console.log('cookie', document.cookie)
```

But doing this i don't get any data in `console.log()`.
How to read cookie in my example?

Comment: `httpOnly` literally means that you can't read the cookie on the client-side (assuming it's spelled correctly in the actual code.)

Comment: @Guy Incognito, could you answer this please?: i send my token fron node js to the front end using cookies, so when i log in i get this cokies, but appears an issue when i want to change the page on react js, in this way on another page i don't have token, how to store cookie with token on front end and to pass it on anothers page ?

Comment: You'd probably get answers to your actual problem if you asked directly about that instead of the [assumed solution](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

- First off, `Authorization` is a request http header so the client should be the one modifying that header.
- Since you're using a **cookie** to store the jwt token, there's no need to use `Authorization` http header since the cookies are automatically sent along with the subsequent requests.
- You could just send a cookie containing the token.

  ```
  res.cookie('jwt', req.token, { httpOnly: true })
  ```
- you could use `passport.jwt` middleware to check for the existence of a `jwt` cookie

  ```
  const cookieExtractor = function (req: Request) {
  let token = null;
  const cookieName = config.jwt.cookieName;
  if (req && req.cookies) {
    token = req.cookies[cookieName];
  }
  return token;
  };
  ```

Comment: for example in `api/login` i send jwt in cookie on ui. After login i have to be redrected on `/home` page, beeing on home page  i make a get request on privete route ehere with node js i check if there are cookie with my jwt, but how can i pass cookie from login page, after login, in home page?